# How to turn a list into collapsible list, using bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the task of creating a mobile view [image: of this menu] and it should look like [image: that] on mobile devices. I am obligated to use bootstrap, but I don't know how to create this functionality. I don't understand how can I, without any jquery, add collapse class or otherwise collapse these items on device width change. 
I tried using panels, but they don't even toggle somehow, even though in the example on the docs everything worked. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class='panel-group' id='my-accordion'>
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h3 class='panel-title' data-target='#panel-1' data-toggle='collapse'>Store & Sites</h3>
            <div class='panel-collapse collapse' id='panel-1'>
                <div class='panel-body'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Our Store</li>
                        <li>Site Map</li>
                        <li>Terms of use</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please give me some ideas.

PS: We are using a third version in our project.

Comment: You posted the same image for the mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you need to include scripts in right order:

1. Bootstrap CSS
2. jQuery
3. jQuery Bootstrap JS

For example:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Possible CSS solution:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .panel-title {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .panel-collapse.collapse:not(.show) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how to uncollapse it on width change.

Comment: You can always use a simple approach with CSS media queries. For example, you could use display: block when the width is more than 768px - this way the collapse will only work on mobile, otherwise it will always show the collapsed content.

Comment: To witch element?

Comment: Element that is collapsed... In your case `id='panel-1'`

Comment: I updated the code with some CSS. If you want to collapse only on mobile, you should change min-width to 576px.